# Force enumitem to be on two digits

Tags: enumitem, latex3

Let us consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item Step one
\item Step two
\item Step three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How can we force the bullet to be automatically on two digits, ie "01", "02", "03", ...,"10".

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

Just use `\int_compare:nNnTF` and do not forget to add `~` between `inner` and `sep`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!20,draw,inner~sep=2pt] (char)
            {
              \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < { 10 }
                { 0#1 }
                { #1 }
            };}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item Step one
\item Step two
\item Step three
\item Step four
\item Step five
\item Step six
\item Step seven
\item Step eight
\item Step nine
\item Step ten
\item Step eleven
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx a lot Stephen! That's perfect

Comment: You’re welcome:-)